# Convert HH:MM Time to Decimal before_save in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a **duration** field that is a decimal data type in my database.

My form accepts **decimals** (e.g. 1.5 hours) but I also want to be able to accept **HH:MM** (e.g. 1:30 for one hour and thirty minutes).

I'd like to be able to detect HH:MM with regex on `before_save` in my model and convert it to decimal so that users can enter either decimal or HH:MM. This part is fine and good, but the problem I'm having is testing the regex against the value in the field.

1:30 gets interpreted as data type `--- !ruby/class 'BigDecimal'` and I can't test it against regex.

Doing `.to_s` on it converts it to 1.0

**How do I get my decimal-typed field to relax and let me convert its value to a string for regex testing in my model?**

Here's my code:

```
# --- Model ---
before_save :convert_duration

def convert_duration
  if duration =~ /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/
    time_pieces = duration.split(":")
    hours = time_pieces[0].to_i
    minutes = (time_pieces[1].to_f/60.0)

    # Final value ready for database
    self.duration = (hours+minutes).round(1)
  end
end
```

*Ruby 1.9.3; Rails 3.2.8*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `duration_before_type_cast` attribute when you want access to the original string.

Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Accessing+attributes+before+they+have+been+typecasted

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius. That's perfect. Thank you!